# Internal page refresh with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and everytime some performs a onchange()-event, the page should run my javascript code again (but a refresh of the page using a new url request is not an option).

Any idea? I know this must be very simple.

my javascript-code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    formObject = document.forms['newBom'];
    var vendor = formObject.elements['inptHardware'].value;
    console.log('selected vendor: ' + vendor);

    var product = formObject.elements['inptProduct'].value;
    console.log('selected product: ' + product); 

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('form[name="newBom"] :input').change(function() {
    // your code there
});
```

Comment: should this one be fired as soon as someone selects an item from a dropdown list or inserts something in a text-input field? Is anything else required in the html code for this to work?

Comment: jQuery applies this to textareas and selects as well, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/hUcZ3/1/

Comment: Nothing else required, Sir. This will be fired when a different option than the previously selected one from a select is selected, when an input text looses focus with a different value than the previous one, etc.